# Dapper ORM Delete functionality with Access

Tags: c#, ms-access, dapper

Today when I was working with Access, I tried to do one test by changing one of the table name in Access but not updating in the code and trying to observe the behavior

For example, My code is

```
Product product = new Product();                                                                                                 //Delete Works well
product.ProductNumber = "P1";
product.Description = "TestProduct1";

var deleteStatement = @"Delete from Product Where Description = @Description";
int outp = con.Execute(deleteStatement, new { Description = product.Description });
```

And my Product table in the database is

[image: And my Product table in the database is]

Before changing 'Description' as 'Descr' things work perfectly. But after changing it when I ran the code (didn't change anything in the code), it deletes entire table. I am confused. Because it is practical that, somebody accidentally changes the table name and not updating in the code. Why this issue is happening? and how to do a validity check for this?

Personally I think, if the field is not in Access database, it should return an exception or not doing anything

**Update**

Currently, I am doing the delete after checking through

```
con.Query<Products>("select ProductNumber, Description from products")
```

This will generate an exception if proper field names are not in the required table. But this couldn't be the answer for this question. I am expecting a proper answer from somebody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue and it seems to be related to the fact that the original field name is `Description`, and the parameter declaration `@Description` causes Dapper to create an `OleDbParameter` whose `.ParameterName` is `Description`.

In the first case, when the column `Description` actually exists, the Access Database Engine recognizes this

```cs
var deleteStatement = @"Delete from Product Where Description = @Description";
//                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

as a valid column name and the DELETE works as expected

After the column as been renamed to `Descr`, the Access Database Engine no longer recognizes `Description` as a field name (because it isn't) so it becomes another parameter placeholder. It *seems* that the result is the statement being evaluated as

```sql
Delete from Product Where Description = Description
```

and since the comparison of a parameter with itself, `Description = Description`, will always be `TRUE` then it is effectively the same as

```sql
Delete from Product Where TRUE
```

and all rows are deleted.

This condition can be avoided by ensuring that the parameter names we supply to Dapper do not match the field names. For example, the following code does throw an exception after the `Description` field has been renamed to `Descr`.

```cs
var deleteStatement = @"Delete from Product Where Description = @d";
int outp = con.Execute(deleteStatement, new { d = product.Description });
```